# What's the difference between the frame rate numbers?

Tags: debugging, firefox-os

In the Firefox OS 1.1.1 debug settings, I can enable an option to show frames per second. [Quote from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Debugging/Developer_settings#Show_frames_per_second):

> Enabling this option adds two indicators at the top of the Firefox OS display, indicating the rate at which screen redraws is occurring, in frames per second.

*Why two indicators, what's the difference between them?*

Comment: Why the close votes? This is a question about a developer tool.

Comment: why do you say two indicators? there is only one indicator for FPS, the other one on the left is for load time I think but I never used it

Comment: More info about the framerate monitor from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Performance#Measuring_performance . In Gaia 1.2 I see three counters though and I don't know which is which.

Comment: @alefteris Perhaps you want to turn that into an answer, with the link and a quote: *"The framerate monitor continuously reports two numbers. The values [...]"?* (i.e. [provide context for links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)) Note that I am asking explicitly about Firefox OS 1.1.1, which is based on [Gaia v1 branch ("v1-train")](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Release_Management/B2G_Landing#Branch_Details).

Comment: The third number, available on Firefox OS >= 1.2 is the fill rate. I think only the leftmost (composition fps) is meaningful to app developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MDN page about [Performance in Firefox OS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Performance#Measuring_performance):

> The framerate monitor continuously reports two numbers. […] The left number is the "composition rate": the estimated number of times per second Firefox OS is drawing frames to the hardware framebuffer. […] The rightmost number is the "layer transaction rate", the estimated number of times per second processes are repainting and notifying the compositor.

In Firefox OS ≥ 1.2, there is a third number that measures the fill rate (thanks [paa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/915844/paa)).